# how to catch the errors in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a rails app in heroku. The values are passed to the server and it works correctly and sometimes it displays an error like

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>   <title>We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)</title>   <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }   </style> </head>

<body>   <!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->   <div class="dialog">
    <h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>
    <p>We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.</p>   </div> </body> </html>
```

so i do not want to get these errors as such. Instead i want to get those error and display something like `unexpected error` in json to the app. How can i do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in application_controller.rb

```
rescue_from "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" do |exception|
   render :json => {:error => 'page not found' }
end
```

Similarly you can add all Exceptions you need in rescue_from method

```
rescue_from "Exception" do |exception|
 render :json => {:error => 'Unexpected error occurred' }
end
```

Comment: No, i did not ask for viewing the errors. I wanted to catch the error and edit the error message and send it as json to app.

Comment: You have mentioned "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound", so do i have to specify each errors and then corresponding json or is there is something which specifies all the errors and display same json for all.

Comment: Sorry. I tried the one you gave next and it is working great. It catches errors. Thank you so much.